# How I do make charge-discharge graph in Semestrix? What is the problem of mine?

Tags: simulation

I don't understand why graph is just pulse. Even that has resistance and capacitor.

Can you give me advice about how to correct and how to do? Thank you!

I am sorry about my not good English ability and style looks newbie.

[image]

Comment: Your voltage probe needs to be across the capacitor, not the source.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen  ohhh Umm then put between capacitor and ground??

Comment: there is no other place that you could put it

Comment: @Stellarlaser Positive leg of probe goes to top of capacitor, right of resistor. Negative leg to ground (if applicable). Otherwise you're not measuring the voltage *across* the capacitor.

Comment: @nanofarad  really thank you!!!! that was somuch helpful